# Need help loading Fonts into webpage from Azure

Tags: html, css, azure, fonts

I am having trouble loading my fonts from Azure into my css/html, making them not appear on my page. Here is my code

```
CSS:@font-face {
font-family: 'DTLArgo-Bold';
src: url('../fonts/dtlargot-bold-webfont.eot');
src: url('../fonts/dtlargot-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../fonts/dtlargot-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../fonts/dtlargot-bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../fonts/dtlargot-bold-webfont.svg#dtl_argot_bold') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
font-family: 'dtl_argot_regular';
src: url('../fonts/dtlargot-webfont.eot');
src: url('../fonts/dtlargot-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../fonts/dtlargot-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../fonts/dtlargot-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../fonts/dtlargot-webfont.svg#dtl_argot_regular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
font-family: 'DTLArgoT-Light';
src: url('../fonts/dtlargot-light-webfont.eot');
src: url('../fonts/dtlargot-light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../fonts/dtlargot-light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../fonts/dtlargot-light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../fonts/dtlargot-light-webfont.svg#dtl_argot_light') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}

.font{
font-family: DTLArgoT-Light, Arial, sans-serif;
}


Azure Web.config:
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>

<system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />  
  <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
  <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
  <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml"  />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-woff" />
</staticContent>    
</system.webServer>
 </configuration>
```

My file structure is root then two folders, one called fonts(for fonts) and the other css(for css).
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!!

Comment: Any chance you're bundling the CSS files?

Comment: Not on the version I have up, I plan on bundling it though

Comment: Please check if the mime-type for these fonts is configured properly in IIS hosting your application. That could be another reason for this issue. You could Remote Desktop into your Virtual Machine and check the settings in IIS management console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using Azure Websites, Azure Webrole or Azure Virtual Machine? Are you developing using just plain HTML, or ASP.NET or PHP or Node?

Asuming you are on the Websites, you have to change a file named `web.config` which is located in the site folder of your web site.

Here is an example of a very simple web.config which registers WOFF files for serving by Azure Websites:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension="woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

You may also want to add a `mimeMap` for all the web-font extensions you use. But be careful to select to correct mime-type, because it may no work. For instance most of the users add `application/x-font-woff` and it may not work for them, because [the RFC, which now is final states it should be](http://www.w3.org/TR/WOFF/#appendix-b) `application/font-woff`.